# Setting value through orm to an auto incremented ID property in Postgreql

Tags: postgresql

I have a model called User. It has auto incremented field of ID. Till now I have Users with IDs generated till 3000 (auto incremented). I have a requirement where I have created a User and setting its ID to 10000. What is the consequence when the auto increment values of ID reach to 10000 from 3000? Will it cause a problem for my application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll be fine so long as the sequence is also updated accordingly, so that its next autoincrementing ID is greater than 10000. You can do this with setval() or alter sequence:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-sequence.html

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-altersequence.html

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply Denis but I am still not clear. Will I have to set the current val manually by altering the sequence when it reaches 10000 or it will be taken care of by postgresql's auto increment?

Comment: The above two methods will let you *set* the next autoincrementing value. In other words, no rows will have an ID between e.g. 3,001 and 10,000: these IDs will just get skipped.

Comment: I completely understand what you are saying. So consider, I alter the sequence and set the current val to 10001. But that means I have to keep a track of the sequence(when it reaches 10000), right?

Comment: No, you're not understanding at all. Alter the sequence so that the next value is 10001. Then add your row (with a mnaully set ID = 10000). And **IGNORE** the other IDs that would have fit in between 3000 and 10000. They're lost forever, never to be used unless you insert more rows manually like so. ID 10000 will never get *reached* by autoincrementing.

Comment: No I got you. Thank you for the solution.